# What to pass for abi encoded arguments

Tags: solidity, remix, polygon, remix-tests

I had cloned usdc contract on polygon test network and deployed it. I want to test deposit method but couldn't able to figure what to pass in depositData( more specifically in which format should i put data in remix)

```
function deposit(address user, bytes calldata depositData)
    external
    override
    only(DEPOSITOR_ROLE)
{
    uint256 amount = abi.decode(depositData, (uint256));
    _mint(user, amount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following online ABI encoder to get the value of `depositData`.

https://www.moesif.com/solidity-abi-hex-decoder/encode

1. Choose `Encode`
2. Input the value, example: `255`
3. Choose the types, `uint256` at this time

An example encoded output: `0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ff`